# Home router with NAT makes internet much slower than with bridged-IP

Tags: networking, router, nat, internet-speed

I have a BeWAN iBox A5100 wireless router and a 100 Mbps direct internet connection (non-DSL). When I use the bridged IP option, speedtest.net reports downlink speed as 85mbps which is quite OK.

When I switch to NAT, the speed drops to 35mbps. The computer where I run the test is connected over 150 mbps WLAN and the rest of the setup is exactly the same. There are no other devices connected to the router. I tried switching between NAT and bridged IP a few times and the result is always the same.
The problem with bridged IP is that my ISP provides a max of 4 public IPs which is not always enough for all connected devices.

My question is, is it some sort of known behavior that NAT is always slower, is it a problem with the router, or something else?

Comment: Sounds like your router's CPU is a little underpowered for its task, maybe you can test another (newer) router? A cheap alternative would be a Raspberry Pi that handles the routing/natting, it runs fast and reliably while consuming very little power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem for many older (and perhaps some lower-end not-so-old) consumer routers. They simply lack the processing power to manage speeds above 20-30 Mbit, (so 35 is "pretty good in the affected class") presumably because they were built to a price point and with the expectation that 10MBit was a "fast" home connection when they were built, so the designers thought they were providing adequate headroom (or their corporate overlords did) within the budget constraints.

NAT is not always **slower**, but it does **take more processing**, so if the processor is not up to the task, it will be slower.

Comment: Thanks! I got my router for free from my ISP as a part of the subscription, so I assume it is on the low end and your explanation makes perfect sense.